# Handling OnChange events using Selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

My problems is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/question/38366302/unable-to-inspect-the-arrow-and-down-button-through-any-approach-in-selenium. I'm unable to use the scroll up and down buttons which is automatically generated by Chrome webdriver. Also I'm unable to type any value in the text input text box. How can I automate this to get the number I want?

[Here you can see the UI Element: Input Box with Scroll buttons which are automatically generated from Chrome web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMJsS.png)

[This is the html code which is related to the UI element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDodL.png)

`actions.ScrollByAmount(0, -100).Perform();` I tried to scroll up after clicking on the input text box but didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It would be good if you can provide some html code of UI and some  screenshots

Comment: @AbhayChaudhary I have added the html code of UI

Comment: @SachithSuraweera updated answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can try below ways to enter value, one of these might work for you

#1
Using javascript executor we will trigger the onchange event on the textbox

```
inputElement.SendKeys("value");
IJavaScriptExecutor jsExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
jsExecutor.ExecuteScript("$(arguments[0]).change();", inputElement);
```

#2 Use the Actions class to simulate a key press and release

```
inputElement.SendKeys("example text");
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(inputElement).KeyDown(Keys.Enter).KeyUp(Keys.Enter).Perform();
```

#3 Use the JavaScriptExecutor to set value and then execute JavaScript code to trigge onchange

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value = 'example text'; arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));", inputElement);
```

#4
Simulate a blur event on the input element. In some cases, triggering the onblur event can also trigger the onchange event

```
// Send keys to the input element
inputElement.SendKeys("example text");

// Simulate a blur event on the input element
inputElement.SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
```

#5 Send keys to the input element using the Return key

```
inputElement.SendKeys("example text" + Keys.Return);
```

#6 Click outside of the input element to trigger the onchange event

```
inputElement.SendKeys("example text");
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(inputElement, 1, 1).Click().Perform();
```